# Is there any function in leaflet that can draw a layer(either marker or circle) on specific angle (eg: 30 degree)?

Tags: javascript, geometry, leaflet, 360-degrees, leaflet-draw

i am trying to get a point on circle's 30 degree angle but don't know the specific thing that i have to try.
Until now i tried two example 
1) get angle by applying formula :  x = Xc + R * cos(angle)
                                    y = Yc + R * sin(angle)

Code :

```
const radius1 = circle.getRadius();
    const cx = 29.505;
    const cy = 70.09;
    const radiusInKm = 500;
    const angleInDegrees = 90;
    // x = Xc + R * cos(theta)
    // y = Yc + R * sin(theta)
    const Xc = cx + radius1 * Math.cos(90);
    const Yc = cy + radius1 * Math.sin(90);
    let marker = L.marker([Xc, Yc]).addTo(this.map);
```

2) use leaflet geometry Utils 
Code:

```
 let A = L.marker([29.505, 70.09]).addTo(this.map);
    let B = geometry.destination(A.getLatLng(), angleInDegrees, radiusInKm * 1000);
    console.log(B.getLatLng());
    L.marker(B).addTo(this.map);
```

before code  imports are 
***import * as L from 'leaflet';
import {geometry} from 'leaflet-geometryutil';***

The problem with 1 is that it gave results as 
Xc = 42574.68122670592 
Yc = -15240.531055110834
and 
the problem with 2 is showing in debugging mode of browser
that is 
"leaflet_geometryutil__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.geometry is undefined"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid , https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/

Comment: are you considering leaflet implementation ?

Comment: i tried to convert latLng into xy , i got the points but not the correct ones.